# Burninate [redundant]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redundant) tag was applied to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27046193/34806) though I cannot imagine how such a tag is useful.

Comment: There is that tag :) Added it in for you. As for the [tag:redundant] tag; it *could* be useful (certainly you could have experts in building redundant systems) but that question was almost certainly mistagged. I removed it for *that* question.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET The redundant tag is not in fact redundant!?  Talk about missed opportunities.  Universe, why you disappoint?

Comment: While I agree that the tag was misused in the cited question, I think it may have to do with [tag:redundancy], so a merger might also be considered.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm not disagreeing with you at all.

Comment: "redundancy" seems valid whereas redundant probably isn't (possibly "redundant-system(s)" instead) and was certainly mis-used.

Comment: The fact that I can fathom all possible redundant use of this tag makes this tag redundant...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET If you find this tag useful then maybe add short description to tag wiki.

Comment: @rtruszk Thats definitely *not* what I was saying. I think it should *burn*. I agree with retagging to redundant-system if anything.

Comment: I was going to suggest this tag for burnination until I saw that doing so  would be...well...   Okay, I'll just upvote the question instead.  (I can see 'redundant-system' or similar retag being useful, though)

Answer (score 2):

Retagged and generally edited all of them to something more useful (better tag which actually captures the meaning the question seemed to imply).

This tag is

[image: Trogdor]

Answer (score 1):

How to defend this tag if it doesn't even have description. We don't know why someone created it. We could only guess. Most of questions are tagged [redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redundant) when 'redundant' word appears in question. It is very weak reason for existence of such tag.

If there is context in which [redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redundant) has sense then someone should write it in tag wiki. Then we could do clean-up removing this tag from most of questions. Now cleaning is difficult. How can we say that tag is added incorrectly to question if we don't know the exact meaning of this tag.

Comment: There are lots of disjoint contexts in which that words has a meaning. Trouble is those contexts are different and assign a different meaning, also there are always better tags already in existence.